# coc.vim failing with :checkhealth command

Tags: node.js, windows, neovim, coc.nvim, rust-analyzer

I'm trying to setup coc for nvim on my Windows os. I installed coc via vim-plug and have the coc.nvim config sourced in my main init.vim file. I recieve these messages when I open neovim and run :checkhealth

coc: health#coc#check                                                                                                 3 ========================================================================                                              4   - OK: nvim version satisfied                                                                                        5   - ERROR: Unable to detect version of node, make sure your node executable is http://nodejs.org/                     6   - ERROR: Javascript entry not found, please compile coc.nvim by esbuild.                                            7   - ERROR: service could not be initialized                                                                           8     - ADVICE:                                                                                                         9       - Use command ":messages" to get error messages.                                                               10       - Open a issue at https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues for feedback.                                    11

I have tried reinstalling node, going to coc.nvim directory and using npm install as well as yarn install (as directed to when I ran :messages after getting errors with :checkhealth). However when I ran yarn build (also directed to when I ran :messages) it said build was not a command of yarn. I’ve searched through other questions and github issues which have been solved by doing the above but none of it has worked here.

Comment: I am running into the same problem apparently. Have you found a solution?